# Embed Swagger3/Swagger 3 UI inside a spring web application

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I Would like to embed swagger3 and swagger3 UI inside an API REST Web Service.

The application web has been developed with spring-boot 1.5.7.RELEASE.

Until now, I have used springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui to easily  achieve the goal.

But unfortunatelly I have discovered that swagger2 do not manage multiple endpoints with same path (and different Accept media content). Normally for versioning purposes.

For instance:

```
===>
GET /api/customer/123 HTTP/1.1 
Accept: application/vnd.company.app.customer-v1+json 

===>
GET /api/customer/123 HTTP/1.1 
Accept: application/vnd.company.app.customer-v2+json
```

Swagger3 manage this, but springfox still not.